# Convert traditional projects to spring boot, without changing applicationContext.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml & tomcat's context.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

The background & requirements are:

1. there are a lot of old projects which have an applicationContext.xml and one or more dispatcher[-XXX]-servlet.xml. We hope those projects can still works while using spring boot(we developed a deployment tools to deploy spring boot applications, but the old projects are still deployed manually). But, @SpringBootApplication can't build the contexts as they were. And rewriting them into codes one by one costs too much, I think.
2. In those project, we use an extended RequestMappingHandlerMapping, so we can't use the native MVC.
3. the context.xml of tomcat, which contains jndi definitions, is maintained by OPs. We have to load it just like tomcat does.
4. i can't find where to set welcome file, which were set in web.xml

I currently using:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
```

Those simple projects without using jndi can startup.

But as my understanding, in this case, the applicationContext and dispatcher-servlet are in the same level(dispatcher-servlet should the child of applicationContext, isn't it?). So, i can't even ensure this one works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did a similar thing about a year ago and your setup was more or less the same as ours and importing those XML files did the trick; the only thing we had to do was to ensure our application class was in a different package hierarchy in order to avoid conflicting/duplicate bean definitions due to its inherent `@ComponentScan`.

And having dispatcher servlet and application context in the same context  won't cause any issues - yes, dispatcher servlet's context is usually defined as a separate context and is a child of the more broad applicationContext but what most people fail to grasp is that that separation only matters if your application wants to have more than one dispatcher servlet, which is rarely the case any more, if it ever was.

In case of multiple dispatcher servlets it was a must to enable them to have different WebMVC configurations, and applicationContext was there to allow you to share common beans and configuration between your servlet contexts so that you don't have to do the same work twice.